# Jmeter Groovy searching for folder and block path in a file

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I am using JSR223 Assertion and I am trying to find the position of these two lines in a file, if not received then assert.

```
  <BlockPath>XYZ\abc\a1\abc</BlockPath>
  <FolderPath>XYZ\abc\a1</FolderPath>
```

I have tried:

```
int pos1 = tstStr.indexOf("<BlockPath>XYZ\abc\a1\abc</BlockPath>");
int pos2 = tstStr.indexOf("<FolderPath>XYZ\abc\a1</FolderPath>");
```

I am getting this error

```
Assertion failure message: javax.script.ScriptException: 
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script32.groovy: 7: unexpected char: '\' @ line 7, column 50.
ted.indexOf("<BlockPath>XYZ\abc\a1\ab
```

I need to literally look for those two lines and get their position. to make sure  is not -1 or they exist in the file . How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

In Groovy you need to escape backslash with another backslash, so you need to amend your code like:

```
int pos1 = tstStr.indexOf("<BlockPath>XYZ\\abc\\a1\\abc</BlockPath>");
int pos2 = tstStr.indexOf("<FolderPath>XYZ\\abc\\a1</FolderPath>");
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Groovy Escape String]

---

Also your response seems to be [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)-based so you can consider using [XPath Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Assertion) instead, it allows asserting response data using [XPath query](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) language so you will be able to check presence of elements like:

```
//BlockPath
```

and

```
//FolderPath
```

Check out [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article to learn more.

Comment: Thank you actually I have tried the backslash and even though the data exist it does not find it.  int pos1 = tstStr.indexOf("<BlockPath>XYZ\\abc\\a1\\abc</BlockPath>");
int pos2 = tstStr.indexOf("<FolderPath>XYZ\\abc\\a1</FolderPath>");